# Check if string contains a word from dictionary python

Tags: python

I just want to check if a given string contains a word from a dictionary

```
names = ["Joe", "Smith", "Nancy"]


string = "Her name was Nancy"

if names in string:
        print(name)
```

for this case i want it to output the name 'Nancy'

Comment: `names` is a list here, not a dictionary. `string` is well, a string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `re`:

```
import re
names = ["Joe", "Smith", "Nancy"]
string = "Her name was Nancy. His name was Smith"

result = re.findall('|'.join(names), string)
print(*result, sep='\n')
```

---

```
Nancy
Smith
```

Comment: Thanks works perfectly! how can i store it inside of a variable instead of printing it? i've tried but it throws an error

Comment: No problem, see my edit!

Answer (score 2):

Hi i think this can solve your problem:

```
string = "Her name was Nancy"
names = ["Joe", "Smith", "Nancy"]
for name in names:
  if name in string:
    print("True")
```

Comment: Thank you this solved it

Answer (score 1):

You can do the following , using `next` with a generator expression and an optional default:

```
name = next((n for n in names if n in string), None)
print(name)
```

Here,

```
x = next(iterator, default)
```

is a shorthand for the following idiom:

```
for x in iterator:
    break        # take the first if present 
else:
    x = default  # or fallback
```

If you only want to match entire words (tokens) within the string, you might want to `str.split` it first:

```
tokens = set(string.split())  # set has a better contains-check
name = next((n for n in names if n in tokens) , None)
```

Some documentation:

- [`next`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#next)
- [`set`](https://python-reference.readthedocs.io/en/latest/docs/sets/#set)
- [`str.split`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.split)
- [for-else and `break`](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#break-and-continue-statements-and-else-clauses-on-loops)
- [generator expressions](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0289/)

Comment: I consider myself a seasoned Python coder and this seems complex even for me. It is nice code, no doubt, but I think it may be a bit above the OP's skill level if they are asking this question. Maybe explain a bit more about `next` in case people aren't sure how using a generator like this works?

Comment: You are right. I added some explanation and docs.

Answer (score 1):

A few things. For one, `names` is a list not a dictionary, and `string` happens to be a string. So there is no dictionary in the code you've provided. Regardless, It looks like you want to see if an element within your list is contained within the string. For that, you should iterate over the list, then check each element to see if it is within your target string. Then you can simply print the match.

```
names = ["Joe", "Smith", "Nancy"]
string = "Her name was Nancy"

for name in names:
    if name in string:
        print(name)
```

Answer (score 0):

Given what you've written, `names` is not a dictionary, but an array. This should do what you want assuming that `names` is indeed an array.

```
names = ["Joe", "Smith", "Nancy"]


string = "Her name was Nancy"

for name in names:
        if names in string:
                print(name)
```

Answer (score 0):

python [list comprehension](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_lists_comprehension.asp) syntax :

```py
[print(name) for name in names if name in string]
```

if you want to store results in a var :

```py
res = [name for name in names if name in string]
```

Comment: Why build a list of `None` values to print the names? Use a regular loop for that.

Comment: Not particularly suitable for this case, you're right. but it is still good for OP to know this python syntax. It coul be more useful if he wanted to get all the matching elements in his string to apply a processing on them later. 
Then he would have to do `[name for name in names if name in string]` and it will save him the hassle to create a list and add matching elements in it in the loop block

Comment: anyway the accepted answer is a regex one... talk about overdoing a task. Btw OP asked in comment of this accepted answer to store it in a variable, so list comprehension fitted very well afterall !